# Interactive game board with Tkinter Python - label updating

Tags: python, canvas, tkinter, visualization, tkinter-canvas

I'm totally new to Tkinter, so apologies if I'm saying something really wrong. I am implementing game fifteen in Python, which I wanna make visual with Tkinter. See the following board of 2x2:

4    3
2    x

If you prompt x to swop with 3, those labels should be updated.So far I initialised a canvas, and have two code snippets, one to set up the board:

```
def visualize():
    for i,row in enumerate(board):
        for j,column in enumerate(row):
            L = Label(root,text='   %s   '%board[i][j],bg='pink')
            if board[i][j] == d*d:
                L = tk.Label(root,text='        ')
```

And for the move function:

```
def move():
    tile = int(raw_input('Which tile would you like to move: '))
    global board, blankx, blanky
    for i in range(d):
        for j in range(d):
            if(board[i][j] == tile):
                if(i - 1 == blanky or i + 1 == blanky or j - 1 == blankx or j + 1 == blankx):
                    board[i][j] = d * d
                    board[blanky][blankx] = tile
                    blanky = i
                    blankx = j
                    return True
    return False
```

Any ideas on how to incorporate the labels into my canvas, and how to incorporate move as a valid event on the canvas? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need animation of moving tile then you could use `grid()` to put labels in rows and columns - instead of using `Canvas` - and move text from label to label.

You could even use `Button` (instead of `Label`) and `command=` to assign functions to buttons.

-

If you need animation then you can use `create_window()` to add `Label`  to `Canvas` and `bind(event, function)` to assign function to label called by event (like ).

But you could also use `place()` to put labels or buttons in `Frame`

-

And you have to keep all label/buttons in global list to have access to them.

-

**EDIT:** simple and working example (but not complet)

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def move(x, y):
    global empty_x, empty_y, game_running   

    if game_running:        
        # check and move tile
        if (empty_x, empty_y) in [(x+1, y), (x-1, y), (x, y+1), (x, y-1)]:

            board[empty_y][empty_x] = board[y][x]
            board[y][x] = ' '

            buttons[empty_y][empty_x]['text'] = buttons[y][x]['text']
            buttons[y][x]['text'] = ' '

            empty_x = x
            empty_y = y

            if won():
                # show label "Hurray"
                label.lift()
                game_running = False

    else:
        # start game again

        shuffle() # shuffle tiles

        game_running = True

        # hide label
        label.lower() # or frame.lift()


def won():

    number = 0

    for y, row in enumerate(board):
        for x, char in enumerate(row, 1):
            number += 1
            if number == 9 and char == ' ':
                #print('A |%s| %d' % (char, number))
                return True
            elif char != str(number):
                #print('B |%s| %d' % (char, number))
                return False

    return True


def shuffle():
    # TODO: shuffle tiles

    # it can't put tiles in random places
    # because it can create game without solution

    pass

# --- data ---

board = [
    ['1', '2', '3'],
    ['4', '5', '6'],
    ['7', '8', ' '],
]

empty_x = len(board[0])-1
empty_y = len(board)-1

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

# create label hidden behide frame

label = tk.Label(root, text="Hurray!\n\n(click any button to play again)", bg="red")
label.grid(row=0, column=0, ipadx=20, ipady=20)

# create frame with buttons to fast show/hide label

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0) # the same (row,col) to hide label

buttons = []

for y, row in enumerate(board):

    buttons_row = []

    for x, char in enumerate(row):

        b = tk.Button(frame, text=char, width=10, height=5, command=lambda x=x,y=y:move(x,y))
        b.grid(row=y, column=x)

        buttons_row.append(b)

    buttons.append(buttons_row)

# start game

shuffle() # shuffle tiles
game_running = True

# start "the engine"

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT**: new version with `StringVar`

In `shuffle` I put tiles in random places and sometimes I get game without solution.

There is few smaller modification - "Hurray" is a button now and starts new game.

```
import tkinter as tk
import random

# --- functions ---

def move(x, y):
    global empty_x, empty_y, game_running   

    if game_running:        
        # check and move tile
        if (empty_x, empty_y) in [(x+1, y), (x-1, y), (x, y+1), (x, y-1)]:

            board[empty_y][empty_x].set( board[y][x].get() )
            board[y][x].set(' ')

            empty_x = x
            empty_y = y

            if won():
                # show label "Hurray"
                label.lift()
                game_running = False

    else:
        # start game again

        shuffle() # shuffle tiles


def won():

    number = 0

    for y, row in enumerate(board):
        for x, string_var in enumerate(row, 1):
            number += 1
            if number == 9 and string_var.get() == ' ':
                #print('A |%s| %d' % (char, number))
                return True
            elif string_var.get() != str(number):
                #print('B |%s| %d' % (char, number))
                return False

    return True


def shuffle():
    global empty_x, empty_y, game_running

    # TODO: shuffle tiles

    # it can't put tiles in random places
    # because it can create game without solution


    # clear all tiles to recognize (in next step) empty tiles 
    for row in board:
        for element in row:
            element.set('')

    # put tiles in random places
    for number in range(1, 10):
        while True: 
            row = random.randint(0, 2)
            col = random.randint(0, 2)
            if board[row][col].get() == '':
                board[row][col].set(str(number))
                print('row/col/number:', row, col, number)
                break

    # last number remove:
    print('empty row/col:', row, col)
    board[row][col].set(' ')
    empty_x = col
    empty_y = row

    # hide label
    label.lower() # or frame.lift()

    # start game
    game_running = True

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

# --- data ---

# StringVar needs `root` - it has to be after tk.Tk()

# empty board
board = [   
#    [tk.StringVar(value='1'), tk.StringVar(value='2'), tk.StringVar(value='3')],
    [tk.StringVar(), tk.StringVar(), tk.StringVar()],
    [tk.StringVar(), tk.StringVar(), tk.StringVar()],
    [tk.StringVar(), tk.StringVar(), tk.StringVar()],
]

# create label hidden behide frame

label = tk.Button(root, text="Hurray!\n\n(click here to play again)", command=shuffle)
label.grid(row=0, column=0, ipadx=50, ipady=50)

# create frame with buttons to fast show/hide label

frame = tk.Frame(root)
frame.grid(row=0, column=0) # the same (row,col) to hide label

buttons = []

for y, row in enumerate(board):

    buttons_row = []

    for x, string_var in enumerate(row):

        b = tk.Button(frame, textvariable=string_var, width=10, height=5, command=lambda x=x,y=y:move(x,y))
        b.grid(row=y, column=x)

        buttons_row.append(b)

    buttons.append(buttons_row)

# start game

shuffle() # shuffle tiles

# start "the engine"

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is really useful! I was wondering whether you know how I could put this into a ' while won() == False: ' so that the game only goes on until the game is solved? It's not working the way I'm trying with simple including this Tkinter snippet into the loop.

Comment: `mainloop()` should be the only (endless) loop in Tkinter. I think you should't  use `while won() == False:`. Better in `move()` use `if won(): print("Hurray!")`

Comment: I modified code to add `won()` function and `"Hurray"` label. I use `Frame` to easily hide all buttons behind label. It still needs `shuffle()` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, saved me a lot of frustration. I did it with labels in the end, and now im trying to work on resetting the board. I thought shuffle() could be the same as init where I set the values for board[i][j]. But it seems like by clicking anywhere after winning, the board stays the same, however the values do go back to the initial board values. I thought after shuffling though the mainloop() will restart itself, and the board will again be set up according to the new (initial) board values. Any idea on where I'm wrong?

Comment: if you have `board` with new values then you have to use it to change buttons text -  `buttons[y][x]['text'] = board[y][x]`

Comment: you can use `tkinter.StringVar()` in board to keep values and assign `StringVar()` to `Button` using `textvariable=` instead of `text=`. When you change value in `StringVar` in board  it will change text on button.

Comment: I made new version with StringVar - see new code in answer.

Comment: Thanks for the updates! Okay, didn't work with merely updating the text label for me. I'm trying to initialize the board (that's given in yours). I want it to be according to the user's input as dimension. Not too familiar with stringvars, but I can't just append it to a list, it seems like. Can you help me with that please? Rest looks fine after the initialization

Comment: you can use `StringVar()` as other objects. You assign it to variable `some_stringvar_text = StringVar()` or append to list `some_list.append(StringVar())` or `some_list.append(some_stringvar_text)` .  But you have to use `get()` and `set()` like `print(some_stringvar_text.get())` and `some_stringvar_text.set("Hello")`. If you have problem then put code on http://pastebin.org or http://ideone.com and send link (like this http://pastebin.com/p2KAfsHH ).

Comment: That might be a better idea:) Here it is: http://pastebin.com/MVXjk1fV Really appreciate your help! The messy part is the setup function. Now the board seems to be fine, but visually it doesn't show that on the window.

Comment: Thanks for this, I changed a few details as it wasn't displaying, and it all works fine. Except one thing: in setup(): I say button.lower() to make it disappear once clicked, but button is a non-referenced variable. So I can't make it disappear after resetting the board. Making it global won't work either.. I just wonder why this is while button.lift() was fine in the play() method

Comment: show code. In previous version there is no `button` variable but `label` and it is reference to `Button`. Maybe you get error message (in console) which could help.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/B6Vq3w6R In setup() for bn.lower() I get: "global name 'bn' is not defined"

Comment: now I see - `setup()` have to be after `bn=Button()` . Now you call `setup() before you create `bn` variablem. Remove first `setup()` - leave second `setup()` - you don't have to call it twice.

Comment: Gooooot it!! There was an extra function call right before root = tk.Tk() ! Thank you :)

Comment: code: http://pastebin.com/C303uP6U . You don't need `buttons = []` any more. You can remove `game_running = True` before `mainloop()` because `setup()` sets `game_running = True`